# How Ethereum prevents miners to sent same transaction multiple time on different blocks?

Tags: mining, evm

For example, `userA` submitted `transactionX` (ex: which send 10 ether to `minerM`), and this is deployed via `minerM` on the block #100.

If `mineM` is an attacker, and it is consecutively elected as a leader on block #101, 102 ...

From the example above, attacker realizes that `transactionX` sends money to itself and want to re-deploy same transaction on a new block.

Can `minerM` or any other miner re-deploy the `transactionX` again, even the `userA` didn't submit it on the second time?

I know it is now possible but:

**[Q]** How Ethereum-Virtual-Machine prevents miners to sent the same transaction, as accepted, more than once in different blocks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each Ethereum address has a counter which tracks how many transactions it has sent. This is called the `nonce`. The nonce is sent along with every new transaction. The same combination of source address and nonce cannot be used multiple times, which is why the attack you described is not possible.

Comment: Can an attacker just change(increment it as one) the 'nonce' and create a updated Tx? @Jesse Busman

Comment: @Alper No, because changing the transaction contents would invalidate the digital signature. The sender of a transaction signs it with their private key. The signature is dependent on the transaction.

Comment: This is not exactly related: from a signed transaction, how could a miner or EVM obtain the original rawTransaction that contains `nonce`, `gasPrice`, `gasLimit`, `to`, `value` and `data` ? @Jesse Busman

Comment: @Alper I'm not really sure what you mean. A raw transaction contains all that data unencrypted. Obtaining them is very trivial.

Comment: I get lost sorry, so along with the signed transaction, sender also sends the signed transaction's raw-version? @Jesse Busman

Comment: @Alper The signed transaction is basically just the raw transaction together with the signature. The raw transaction is physically part of the signed transaction, so obtaining that data is trivial. Terminology gets a bit mixed up, something the signed transaction is called the raw transaction. The point is, the data you asked about is physically present, unencrypted, inside both the raw transaction and signed transaction.